# How would I assign values based on a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have this CTE which I want to bring back a certain result in the SCHEDULEDQUANTITY column based on what the PRODUCTIONORDERSTATUS column value is. If the PRODUCTIONORDERSTATUS is 3 or 4 then I just want the original value of the SCHEDULEDQUANTITY column displayed but if it is anything else then the SCHEDULEDQUANTITY should be 0.

How do I achieve this? I tried using case but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
POH (ITEMNUMBER, SCHEDULEDQUANTITY,CASE1)
    AS
        (
            SELECT ITEMNUMBER, SUM(SCHEDULEDQUANTITY),
            CASE
                WHEN PRODUCTIONORDERSTATUS != 3 THEN SCHEDULEDQUANTITY = 0
                OR PRODUCTIONORDERSTATUS != 4 THEN SCHEDULEDQUANTITY = 0
                ELSE SCHEDULEDQUANTITY
            END AS CASE1
            FROM POH 
            GROUP BY ITEMNUMBER
        )
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you. The above won't work as you have multiple columns yo aren't aggregating that are not in the `GROUP BY` clause. Also you appear to have a `THEN` with a boolean expression (`SCHEDULEDQUANTITY = 0`); `CASE` is an expression and returns a scalar value, not a mix of boolean results and scalar values.

Comment: Also. "it doesn't seem to be working." is pretty meaningless, if you get errors (which you do), tell us the errors